# Why am I getting (null) after scanf?

Tags: null, scanf

I don't understand why am I getting (null) after running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input;

    printf("enter string: ");
    scanf("s", input);

    printf("%s", input);
}
```

[image]

Why am I getting (null) after scanf?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your answer is that you have a char variable `input`, but it is not initialized with a length. As a result, it prints `(NULL)`. To overcome this issue, you should change your declaration of `input` to something like:

```
 char input[30];
```

This way, you can store up to 30 chars in your `input` variable. Note that I used 30 as an example; you can use any value of your choice here.

Secondly, the line:

```
 scanf("s", input);
```

Is invalid; it should be:

```
 scanf("%s", input);
```

Because `%s` is a placeholder for the variable given after the string; here it is `input`. `%s` refers to a placeholder for a string or char[] data-type s is the correct syntax.

** As an aside, since you want to read an entire sentence as input, you should know that your code will only work for accepting input until a spacebetween the first word and the next one, because `scanf()` does not read a space. To learn more anout using strings, refer to this link: [C Programming Strings](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a length for yout char, i.E. char[25]. The char now keeps a single character.

Comment: "input" might also be a reserved word. Try char answer[25] or so.